# How to search through a file and read it in

Tags: java, csv

I have a csv file that has the age, and name. And I want to search the file for everyone who's age is 30 and display their name and age. How can I do that in Java?
I know I can read it to an `ArrayList`, I'm just not sure how to go about doing that.

Here's what I have so far:

```
 public static void gradeRead(String filename)
 {
  try{
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(filename);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

  String fileLines;
  String[] parts;


  while(br.ready())
  {
    fileLines = br.readLine();

    parts = fileLines.split(",");

    System.out.println(parts[0] + " " + parts[1];
  }

  br.close();
  } 
  catch(IOException e)
  {
    System.out.println("Couldnt Read file");      }
}
```

I know how to read it in to the string array, but I don't know how to add it to the `ArrayList` and then search it. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Care to post your work?

Comment: First try googling for it, make an attempt to code it, and add some code in this post, please.

Comment: here's some tips: http://demeranville.com/how-not-to-parse-csv-using-java/

Comment: there i updated it. Didnt think yee would think I havent attempted it

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to have a Person class and instantiate it in each line (with age and name). And a PersonCatalog class for read file and search:

```
public class PersonCatalog
{
    private List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();

    public void readFile(String filePath) throws NumberFormatException, IOException
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(filePath)));
        String currentLine;
        int index = 0;
        while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            String[] pair = currentLine.split(",");
            if(index != 0)
            {
                persons.add(new Person(pair[1].trim(),Integer.valueOf(pair[0].trim())));
            }
            index++;
        }
        reader.close();
    }

    public List<Person> searchByAge(int age)
    {
        List<Person> results = new ArrayList<Person>();
        for(Person p : persons)
        {
            if(p.getAge() == age)
            {
                results.add(p);
            }
        }
        return results;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        PersonCatalog personCatalog = new PersonCatalog();
        personCatalog.readFile("G:/test.csv");
        List<Person> persons = personCatalog.searchByAge(30);
        for(Person person : persons)
        {
            System.out.println(person.getName() + " " + person.getAge());
        }
    }
}

public class Person
{
    private String name;
    private Integer age;

    public Person(String name, Integer age)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public Integer getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }
}
```

input:

```
age, name
11, sam
15, jack
3, nani
30, david
```

output:

```
david 30
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using *Windows Operating System* I would suggest using the Type 1 JDBC driver. Because you just want to print the record. However as you know this driver doesn't support networking. If all these are satisfied, then here is a solution.

```
import java.sql.*;
class csv1
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

    Connection c=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:google");

    Statement s=c.createStatement();

    ResultSet rs=s.executeQuery("select * from sample.csv where age=20");

        while(rs.next())
        {
        System.out.println(rs.getObject(1)+"  "+rs.getObject(2));
        }

    s.close();
    c.close();
    }
}
```

**google** is the dsn name.

**Note:** The *sample.csv* must exist in that directory where you execute the program. If it is another directory mention the full path.

Example: `C:\\sample1.csv` instead of `sample1.csv`

**Reference:** [How to read csv file using JDBC](http://java-demos.blogspot.com/2014/02/read-csv-file-using-jdbc.html)